# How to override APP_GUARD in E2E tests

Tags: typescript, nestjs, e2e-testing

I'm writing E2E tests for my NestJS project and I bumped into one issue I could not solve.

This is my setup fragment

```js
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [AppModule], // AppModule imports AuthModule
})
  .overrideProvider(APP_GUARD) // Not working
  .useClass(MockedAuthGuard)
  .compile();

app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication<NestExpressApplication>();
```

The goal is to use `MockedAuthGuard` instead of real `AuthGuard` in my tests.

The problem is that it has no effect. It still hits a real class instead of my mock version.

What I tried is to modify my module like so

```js
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: Env.isE2E ? MockedAuthGuard : AuthGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And now it works, but I don't like this part `Env.isE2E ? MockedAuthGuard : AuthGuard`. I want to keep it clean and only override it in E2E tests.

What am I missing here? How can I make it work by using `overrideProvider` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `useClass` with the`APP_GUARD` provider, you can add the `AuthGuard` to the `providers` array directly, and then use `useExisting: AuthGuard` for the `APP_GUARD` provider. Then, in your tests you can properly use `overrideProvider(AuthGuard).useClass(MockedAuthGuard)` without any issue, leaving your modules clean, and your tests the only ones referencing the mocks.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useExisting: AuthGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did a trick. But specifying `AuthGuard` 2 times kinda looks weird to me. I also made it work by mocking the module itself. `overrideModule(AuthModule).useModule(MockedAuthModule)` worked without any issues.